# SQL Query: How to make a query for identifying a post without a specific 'Tag'?

Tags: sql

posts has tags

table poststags with postid, tagid as fields

How do I create a SQL statement/query so I can get a list of posts without a specific tag.

```
SELECT posts.postid FROM post
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.postid = posts.postid
WHERE tags.tagid != 5
```

The statement above won't work.

```
post 1 with tags 1, 2, 3
post 2 with tags 1, 5
post 3 with tags 2, 3, 5
```

I want the result to be post 1 because it doesn't have tagid 5

Answer (score 2):

An alternative...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  posts
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
      FROM tags
     WHERE tags.postid = posts.postid
       AND tags.tagid = 5
  )
```

The exact anti-semi-join *(rows where something **does not exist** in another table)* with the best performance depends on the database you're using.

*(Although never use `NOT IN()` for this type of problem.  `NULL`s will mess you around and performance will often suck.)*

Comment: Whomever upvoted this, but not the `LEFT JOIN`, is mean beyond reproach

Answer (score 1):

An anti-join will do the job. For example:

```
select p.*
from post p
left join tags t on p.postid = t.postid and t.tagid = 5
where t.tagid is null
```